# Error message when opening Pdf document using zend_PDF

Tags: zend-framework, magento, zend-pdf, magento-1.7

I am trying to generate PDF using Zend_PDF component in magento 1.7 and have tried the following code in my custom controller

```
 public function getPdf()
 {
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
 $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
 $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
 $page->setFont($font, 24)
   ->drawText('That which we call a rose,', 72, 720);
 $pdf->pages[0] = $page;
   $pdfString = $pdf->render();
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
echo $pdfString;
   }
```

After calling this method in phtml file. It successfully creates PDF document. But when I try to open this PDF document. It throws error saying :
Adobe reader couldn't open myfile.pdf because it's not either a supported file type or because the file has been damaged............
Can any help me in resolving this issue!!!

Comment: Are there any errors in log files? Have you tried removing header functions to see if PDF is generated or it just throws some error?

Comment: After removing header function it simply displays mixture of alphanumeric charecters like this.......%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$pdfString = $pdf->render();`, you will need to save this file.

So, add this after that line:

```
$pdf->save('myfile.pdf');
```

Comment: I have tried r $pdfString = $pdf->render(); after  $pdf->save('myfile.pdf');. Unfortunately It still throws the errors saying : Adobe reader couldn't open myfile.pdf because it's not either a supported file type or because the file has been damaged...........